# scrolling shortcuts in Cygwin terminal less output

Tags: terminal, cygwin, vertical-scrolling, less-unix

What keyboard shortcuts can I use to scroll up and down in an output that has been piped to `less` in the Cygwin terminal application?

I like being able to scroll in less using 'Shift'+'PgUp/PgDn', but when working with a large piped output today, I could not use the same commands. I couldn't find a specific answer to this in Google or stackoverflow.

Comment: Are you asking about scrolling in `less`, or scrolling from the command line?

Comment: Scrolling in the output from piping to 'less'. In the command line, I am able to scroll via 'Shift'+'PgUp' or 'PgDn', but cannot do that in 'less'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`less` in Cygwin, at least when used with minTTY, responds to PgUp / PgDown (no shift) correctly. It also handles the mouse scroll wheel.